# python yumbase install not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, rpm, yum

I have a `RHEL 7.2 box`, here's the scenario that i have:

I have 2 use cases, one of them is working the second one is not working

1. I have the following packages on my machine:

rocksdb.x86_64                   3.10.0-11.el7
rocksdb-devel.x86_64             3.10.0-11.el7

And i'm passing this package to the `install` function: `rocksdb-devel-3.10.0-8.el7.x86_64` which should bring the dependencies (rocksdb-3.10.0-8.el7.x86_64)

2. I don't have rocksdb installed at all

I'm passing the same package to the `install` function.

```
Here's a snippet of my code:

 class YumYum(object):
    installed_packages = None
```

def **init**(self):
            self.yb = yum.YumBase()
            self.yb.conf.assumeyes = True
            #self.yb.conf.cache =1
            #self.yb.setCacheDir()
            self.non_devel_packages = []
            self._probe_installed_packages()

```
def _probe_installed_packages(self):
        inst = self.yb.rpmdb.returnPackages()
        self.installed_packages = [
            Package(
                x.name,
                x.version,
                x.release,
                strict=False) for x in inst]

def _execute(self):
        message(OKGREEN, "Performing cleanup...")
        self._cleanup()
        message(OKGREEN, "After cleanup")
        self.yb.resolveDeps()
        self.yb.buildTransaction()
        self.yb.processTransaction()

    def _cleanup(self):
        self.yb.cleanRpmDB()
        self.yb.cleanExpireCache()
        self.yb.cleanMetadata()
        self.yb.cleanSqlite()
        self.yb.cleanPackages()

    def install(self, package)
        self.yb.install(
                        name=pkg.name, version=str(
                            pkg.version), release=str(
                            pkg.release), arch="x86_64")
        self._execute()

    def remove(self, package)
        self.yb.remove(name=pkg.name, version=str(pkg.version))
            self._execute()
# Main

yumyum = YumYum()
yumyum.remove(package) # In my real code the remove won't be called if i haven't found any packages to be removed (I.E if i haven't found a new newer packaged which is currently installed than needed)
yumyum.install(package)
```

**In the first scenario** The packages are being removed, but the installtion is failing with this Exception:

```
File "./pd-build.py", line 617, in _execute
    self.yb.processTransaction()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 6503, in processTransaction
    self._doTestTransaction(callback,display=rpmTestDisplay)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 6582, in _doTestTransaction
    raise Errors.YumRPMCheckError,retmsgs
yum.Errors.YumRPMCheckError: [u'ERROR with transaction check vs depsolve:', 'rocksdb(x86-64) = 3.10.0-8.el7 is needed by rocksdb-devel-3.10.0-8.el7.x86_64']
```

**In the second scenarion**: it's performing the installation right a way without any errors.

So in order trying to reproduce the the error(in the first scenarion) i've executed the same commands with `yum cli` and it managed to remove and ind install everything.

**I'm wondering** if i'm missing any configuration in the YumBase class or other things.